# Trying to read file

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I'm trying to write a file with strings and then read it. But when I read it looks wierd with squares and stuff.. I couldn't copy paste!

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ObjectOutputStreamDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        //Now Im writing
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("fruit.dat"));

        String ord[] = { "Banana", "Mango", "Apple", "Passionfruit","Orange" };

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            output.writeObject(ord[i]);
        }
        output.close();

        //Now Im trying to read.
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fruit.dat"));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem with file.");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Short answer: if you're going to use `ObjectOutputStream` to write to a file, you should be using `ObjectInputStream`, **not a `BufferedReader`**, to read the file back in. Conversely if you want to read a file using a `Reader`, you should be writing the file with a `Writer`.

Answer (score 5):

You're creating an `ObjectOutputStream` - that's basically a *binary* file full of serialized objects. It's not in any way a text file, and shouldn't be treated as such.

If you want a text file, you want a `Writer` of some description - e.g. an `OutputStreamWriter` wrapping a `FileOutputStream`. If you want to write a line at a time, you may want to wrap that `OutputStreamWriter` in a `BufferedWriter`.

It's very important that you understand the distinction between "a binary file containing serialized strings" and "a text file".

Comment: Allright! But I need to use ObjectOutputStream. How can I change my reader to get it right?

Comment: @user1051477: Use `ObjectInputStream` - that's the opposite side of an `ObjectOutputStream`, effectively, which knows how to read the data written by an `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: Use them in pairs BufferedWriter with a BufferedReader or object writer with an object reader